# How to group json array data if exits the same value android studio

Tags: android, json

I have Json like this,
I want to group by sub_name to get array of Phone, Mobile Operation(Every array have the same data value get only one of array).

```
 category: {
    cate: [
    {
    sub_id: "568",
    sub_name: "Phones",
    ns_id: "17002",
    ns_name: "Mobile Phone"
    },
    {
    sub_id: "568",
    sub_name: "Phones",
    ns_id: "18787",
    ns_name: "Other Phones"
    },
    {
    sub_id: "372",
    sub_name: "Mobile Operation",
    ns_id: "3650",
    ns_name: "Sim Card"
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not getting your question. please explain more

Comment: are you parsing your json?

Comment: What you have tried till?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ArrayList and add your data.Before adding 2nd item every time check your ArrayList has same data or not using for loop with the help of arrayList size.

Whatever I understood about your query I made this code....

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList phones = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList Mobile_Operation = new ArrayList<>();
String data = "  category: {\n" +
        "    cate: [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "    sub_id: \"568\",\n" +
        "    sub_name: \"Phones\",\n" +
        "    ns_id: \"17002\",\n" +
        "    ns_name: \"Mobile Phone\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "    sub_id: \"568\",\n" +
        "    sub_name: \"Phones\",\n" +
        "    ns_id: \"18787\",\n" +
        "    ns_name: \"Other Phones\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "    sub_id: \"372\",\n" +
        "    sub_name: \"Mobile Operation\",\n" +
        "    ns_id: \"3650\",\n" +
        "    ns_name: \"Sim Card\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "    }";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject categoryObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("category");
        JSONArray jsonArray = categoryObject.getJSONArray("cate");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            String datal = ((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i)).getString("sub_name");
            if (datal.equalsIgnoreCase("Phones"))
                phones.add(jsonArray.get(i));
            else if (datal.equalsIgnoreCase("Mobile Operation"))
                Mobile_Operation.add(jsonArray.get(i));
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,((JSONObject)phones.get(1)).getString("ns_name"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, try

```
String subName = "Phones";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("cate");
JSONArray groupJsonWithSubName = new JSONArray();

for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    if(jsonData.getString("sub_name").equals(subName){
         groupJsonWithSubName.put(jsonData);
    }
}
// in here groupJsonWithSubName will contains all json object which have sub_name="Phones"
```